# FFMpeg with PHP-7.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a NGINX server with PHP-7.0 and I would like to install the ffmpeg-php extension. I've been trying for a few days now and in many ways.

The method that worked so far was compiling ffmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-4.0.2.tar.bz2) manually, but when trying to compile ffmpeg-php (https: // sourceforge. net / projects / ffmpeg-php / files / ffmpeg-php / 0.6.0 / ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2 / download) I am encountering the following error message:

> root@zumbiserver-mercury:~/php7-ffmpeg# make /bin/bash
>
> /root/php7-ffmpeg/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/php7-ffmpeg
>   -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/php7-ffmpeg/include -I/root/php7-ffmpeg/main -I/root/php7-ffmpeg -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c -o ffmpeg-php.lo libtool: compile:  cc
>   -I. -I/root/php7-ffmpeg -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/php7-ffmpeg/include -I/root/php7-ffmpeg/main -I/root/php7-ffmpeg -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg-php.o In
>   file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:104:0,
>                    from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_stream.h:28,
>                    from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:41,
>                    from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
>                    from /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c:40: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:91:21: error: field
>   ‘st_atim’ has incomplete type
>        struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access.  */
>                        ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:92:21: error: field
>   ‘st_mtim’ has incomplete type
>        struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification.  */
>                        ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:93:21: error: field
>   ‘st_ctim’ has incomplete type
>        struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change.  */
>                        ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:152:21: error: field
>   ‘st_atim’ has incomplete type
>        struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access.  */
>                        ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:153:21: error: field
>   ‘st_mtim’ has incomplete type
>        struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification.  */
>                        ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:154:21: error: field
>   ‘st_ctim’ has incomplete type
>        struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change.  */
>                        ^ In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_stream.h:28:0,
>                    from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:41,
>                    from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
>                    from /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c:40: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:364:31: error: array type has
>   incomplete element type ‘struct timespec’
>            const struct timespec __times[2],
>                                  ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:371:54: error: array type has
>   incomplete element type ‘struct timespec’  extern int futimens (int
>   __fd, const struct timespec __times[2]) __THROW;
>                                                         ^ In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:395:0,
>                    from /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c:40: /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.h:218:2: error:
>   unknown type name ‘time_t’   time_t                         expires;
>
>   ^ /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.h:248:86: error:
>   unknown type name ‘time_t’  CWD_API realpath_cache_bucket*
>   realpath_cache_lookup(const char *path, int path_len, time_t t);
>                                                                                         ^ /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c: In function ‘zm_startup_ffmpeg’:
>   /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c:108:5: warning: implicit declaration of
>   function ‘avcodec_init’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>        avcodec_init();
>        ^ /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c:111:5: warning: ‘av_register_all’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>        av_register_all();
>        ^ In file included from /root/php7-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php.c:43:0: /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:2025:6: note: declared here 
>   void av_register_all(void);
>
> ```
>   ^ Makefile:194: recipe for target 'ffmpeg-php.lo' failed make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
> ```

Can someone give me a light? I do not know what else to do!

Comment: Why would you use an obsolete PHP version like 7.0? I'd expect at least 7.1 if not 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ffmpeg-php is a long dead project that hasn't been updated for 10 years. Don't waste your time. If you must use a wrapper see [FFmpegPHP](https://github.com/char0n/ffmpeg-php) or [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) which appear to be actively maintained as of now.

Do you even need a wrapper? Perhaps you can just directly use the `ffmpeg` tool in your scripts. See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).